# What options exist for self service password reset for Exchange Online users

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, exchange-server

We recently migrated Exchange on-premise to Exchange Online. We now have the issue where remote users cannot reset their password for our on-prem AD(previously they could use the exchange web app).

The only option I'm seeing is to pay for Azure AD premium which allows password write-back to our local AD.

What if we deployed a domain controller in Azure or Azure domain services. Would we be able to get self-service password resets doing this or would we still need Azure AD premium?

Any other options out there that aren't $6 a user?

Thanks!

Comment: Dang, nobody out there has ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using Azure domain services or adding a domain controller in Azure will not help. I think you can still use OWA for exchange online to reset the password (but I am not an exchange guy, so cannot confirm). If exchange does not have that option, then you will have to use premium licenses.

Comment: Yeah, premium license or 3rd party seem to be the only options. Thanks!